# Web Parser using multiple threads

Tags: node.js, multithreading

I want to build a web parser using node.js.

I know using multithreading won't automatically get a performance benefit but since this parser is interacting with the internet there are the connection delays.

When the parser requests a website it will take several hundred milliseconds if not longer where the CPU simply has to wait for the request to complete.
For a single thread this would mean that it is waiting most of the time.

I want to use threading to distribute available CPU resources better.

I want to run several workers that perform the requests along with some other methods.

I found the cluster module could be useful but I'm not sure about this since most examples speak of using it as webserver.

How is this best achieved using node.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @roman-dibikhin answered, check the [Async queue](https://github.com/caolan/async#queue) module.

If you build your code correctly - the limit will be your network bandwidth \ sql \ disk much before the single core.

I just seen a project that use node for url scrapping. The limit is only the internet bandwidth.

of course if you want you can always fire another instance.

Comment: is that project open source? What's the best way to fire up multiple instances instead of starting them manually from console? Is there something that already has X instances running and when one finishes another one gets launched automatically?

Comment: Not open source, sorry. The basic way to fire multiple instances is by 'child process', you can manage the number of concurrent by async queue, by promises or anything else. The best way is really depends on your targets and the way you write your code.

Comment: Thanks, do you know a way to make web requests with cookie support? Is curl the way to go?

Comment: npm request is the way to go

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Async](https://github.com/caolan/async) NPM to use all power of one core and then scale with some [clustering solution](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/node-js-performance-scaling-proxies-clusters/) to use all cores.